# remoteMessage firebase expecting function invocation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm learning firebase cloud messaging. I've implemented it in app run notification, but it seems that doesn't work. The problem is that, when I use the firebase keyword called `remoteMessage`, it says that it needs to be an invocation. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.fbtutorial

import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
import com.google.firebase.messaging.ktx.remoteMessage

class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {

        Looper.prepare()

        Toast.makeText(baseContext, remoteMessage.notification?.title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() // here at remoteMessage I have and error saying "Function invocation 'remoteMessage(...)' expected"

        Looper.loop()
    }
}
```

if you know why i get this error please tell me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RemoteMessage` parameter to `onMessageReceived` is called `p0`, so to get its title you'd do:

```
p0.notification?.title
```

I recommend carefully reading and following the code in the Firebase documentation on [overriding `onMessageReceived`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived), as using the parameter names that are used there makes it more likely that your other code will also compile without syntax errorss

Comment: oh, I didn't see that, thanks that worked!